# Required DataAnnotation for Enum not working in Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

When I submit my form with a null Name, I get a client-side error message on my page. When I submit with a null AttributeType, there are no client-side errors. How can I get the "Required" attribute to work with an Enum?

```
public class AttributeName
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Attribute Type is required")]
    public Enums.AttributeType? AttributeType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Just for clarification, when I try to submit the form with a null AttributeType, it DOES create a ModelState error, but the client-side validation DOESN'T prevent it from posting to the page handler. On the other hand, when I submit with a null Name, the client-side validation DOES prevent it from posting to the page handler.

Enum constructor looks like this:

```
public enum AttributeType
{
    List = 1,
    Text = 2,
    Number = 3,
    Decimal = 4
}
```

Razor page looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 form-group">
        <label asp-for="AttributeName.AttributeType"></label>
        <select asp-for="AttributeName.AttributeType" asp-items="Model.AttributeTypeList">
            <option>Select:</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="AttributeName.AttributeType" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 form-group">
        <label asp-for="AttributeName.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="AttributeName.Name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AttributeName.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is how I populate the AttributeType list:

```
AttributeModel.AttributeTypeList = WebUtil.GetEnumValues<Enums.AttributeType>();

public static List<SelectListItem> GetEnumValues<T>()
        {
            return Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = Regex.Replace(x, "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim(), Value = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), x)).ToString() }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Did you see this question that was asked previously? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548796/how-to-make-requiredattribute-work-with-an-enum-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548796/how-to-make-requiredattribute-work-with-an-enum-field)

Comment: Unfortunately, removing a "none" option and using a nullable Enum didn't work for me. That answer is over 5 years old (probably not .NET Core / Razor) I know one of the answers on that page is to just write custom validation code, but what good is the "Required" annotation if I need to write custom code?

Comment: Could you show your razor pages code?I could not reproduce it, see my [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwVSb.gif)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that AttributeType is a list. I'm not sure if that mattered or not.

Comment: @Primico, Did you solve this for client-side validation in the meantime?